# Centralized apache logging with rsyslog

Tags: linux, centos, logging, rsyslog

I maintain many virtualhosts (over 60) hosted on a Centos server running Apache. The virtualhosts gets created using Plesk, which creates separate log files for each domain using the following pattern `/var/www/vhosts/<domain_name>/statistics/logs/{access,error}_log`.

I would like to centralize all these logs on another server to parse them with elasticsearch + logstash. Currently I have a bash script which create a `<domain>.conf` file in the `/etc/rsyslog.d/` for each domain contained in the `/var/www/vhosts` dir, with the following configuration:

```
InputFileName /var/www/vhosts/<domain_name>/statistics/logs/access_log
$InputFileTag apache-access:
$InputFileStateFile state-apache-access
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

Is there a way to create a single .conf file which will send all the logs to my central logging server? Something like `$InputFileName /var/www/vhosts/*/statistics/logs/access_log`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK rsyslog doesn't support wildcards in filenames. [nxlog](http://nxlog.org) does. In addition it can parse apache logs and can send it to elasticsearch over http. You might want to take a look at it. (Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with the project.)